# "I wish there were," or "I wish there was," which sounds most natural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, subjunctive-mood

Given the choice of these two, which sound most natural?

I wish there **were** something I could do for you.
I wish there **was** something I could do for you.

If both sound equally natural, I'd prefer the first.

Comment: Which sounds more natural is subjective. Even to the same person at different times or regarding certain vocabulary or the perceived formality.

Comment: Of course if the "something" is plural it is always "were" e.g. *I wish there were chairs to sit on".

Comment: I will give you permission to use the first.  (I like it better too!)

Comment: Thanks, WS2. I was wondering if "something" could take a plural.

Comment: Appreciated, aparente001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions that need to be answered here.

First, is there still the slightest chance that there *is* something I can do for you? For example, I might think that there is probably nothing I can do for you, but I still need to think about it a bit before I can be sure. In that case, I'll say "I wish there *was* something I could do for you."

Second, how formal is the language you're using? If there is absolutely no chance that I can do anything for you, and I'm speaking formally, then I should say "I wish there *were* something I could do for you." If there's no chance at all that I can do anything for you, and I'm speaking in a neutral or informal register, then I can use either *was* or *were*.

Comment: 1. I would like to make it sound as if there's nothing that can be done. 2. It's in an informal context. By the way, what do you make of WS2's comment above? WS2 writes that if "something" is plural, then it is always were.

Comment: @user49640, would you mind explaining why it makes a difference whether or not there is a chance? Is it because having to think about it makes it a hypothetical, and therefore we need to use subjunctive mood, while if we're really sure there's no chance, then it's not hypothetical, so we use indicative mood?